# Monitoring of Azure VPN Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-vpn

We have a VPN Gateway in Azure with sku VpnGw1, so it should be able to handle 650 Mb/s.
We have one S2S connection and we've enabled P2S connectivity.

I would like to monitor the VPN Gateway so I know when we're getting close to the 650 Mb/s.

I assume that the 650 Mb/s is the bandwith consumed by both P2S and S2S. Or?

I've been looking at the metrics available but don't really understand what they tell me.
I've found these metrics that should be of intrest: Tunnel Bandwidth, Gateway S2S Bandwidth and Gateway P2S Bandwidth.

I've seen this site but I don't think it really explains the differences enough:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/monitor-vpn-gateway

These are the values I get when I look at the three metrics. It doesn't make sense to me.
Can someone explain to me?

[image: These are the values I get when I look at the three metrics]

Answer (score 0):

Azure VPN Gateway with sku VpnGw1 has Throughput Benchmark 650 Mb/s.
P2S and S2S both consume 650 Mb/s bandwidth of Azure VPN Gateway.

Throughput Benchmark is metric calculated by Azure. It is obtained by running iperf3 between VNets in the same region, with minimum duration of 120 seconds and up to 32 flows.

Metrics that are available in Azure Monitor for monitoring Azure VPN gateways have different display names:

- AverageBandwidth -> Gateway S2S Bandwidth
- P2SBandwidth -> Gateway P2S Bandwidth
- TunnelAverageBandwidth -> Tunnel Bandwidth

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported.md

You can check real bandwidth of Azure VPN Gateway by running Iperf test from your location.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-validate-throughput-to-vnet#run-iperf-iperf3exe

Or by using Azure Throughput Analyzer Tool

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52038&from=https%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownloads%2F5c8189b9-53aa-4d6a-a086-013d927e15a7%2Fdefault.aspx

You can check latency from your location to Azure VPN Gateway by using link below
https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Latency

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-azure-vpn-gateways-now-6x-faster/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what I am asking for is how can I monitor the gateway to get noticed when there is too much traffic.
What does TunnelAverageBandwidth mean? I first thought that it would be the load of P2S and S2S combined but when I look at the numbers in my picture it can't be like that, so clearly I was wrong about that.
So how can I get info about the amount of traffic in the VPN Gateway?

Comment: You may set up Azure Monitor alerts based on metrics to get noticed when there is too much traffic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-setup-alerts-virtual-network-gateway-metric#setup

Comment: TunnelAverageBandwidth - average bandwidth utilization of tunnels created on the gateway for the last 5 minutes. P2SBandwidth - average bandwidth utilization of tunnels created on the gateway for the last 1 minute.